# Simulated Communities with Pareto Distribution of Generalists

Tags: r, for-loop

The code below allows you to generate 100 realistic food webs. Instead of column-matrix associations, food webs are constructed in a series of three columns representing 'plants', 'herbivores' and 'enemies'. For each ecosystem of the simulation, a unique tritrophic web is constructed. Ecosystems are constructed by randomly selecting individuals from a lognormal abundance distribution and a pareto-distributed diet breadth for both consumer levels. NOTE: there is always a basal plant for each row of the interaction web, even without consumers.

We need to force the community to have a Pareto distribution of diet breadth (diet specialization), such that it includes broad generalists. Currently, the way it is written, the tail of broad generalists disappears. You will notice that the "broad generalists" only reach ~15 plants max in some of the distributions. This should be much greater since we have 100s of plants in these communities.

Here is the code for the communities:

```
library(doParallel)
library(vegan)
library(VGAM)

 dFlooredParetoI <- function(x,alpha,xmin=NA,xmax=NA) {
  ## Set xmax or infer it from x as max(x)?
  if(is.na(xmax)) {
  xmax <- max(x)
   }
  ## Set xmin or infer it from x as min(x)?
  if(is.na(xmin)) {
  xmin <- min(x)
   }

  return( (VGAM::ppareto(x+1,shape=alpha) - VGAM::ppareto(x,shape=alpha))/
        (VGAM::ppareto(xmax+1,shape=alpha) - VGAM::ppareto(xmin,shape=alpha)) )
}

rFlooredParetoI <- function(n,alpha,xmin=1,maxval) {
if(maxval!=round(maxval)) { warning("maxval must be an integer!")}
ps <- dFlooredParetoI(xmin:maxval, alpha)
 counts <- rmultinom(1,n,ps)
## this next line gives us counts[1] 1s, counts[2] 2s, ...
## then shuffles those and returns the vector.
return(sample(rep(which(counts>0), counts[which(counts>0)])))
 }




cl<-makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cl)

 ## ABUNDANCE, SPECIES, AND DIET BREADTH (1=PLANT, 2=HERBIVORE, 3=PSIT), 
 RAMPED UP EACH PART OF THE LOOP 
 ## (THIS IS LIKE A 1000 M^2 PLOT SIZE, SO SCALE UP IF YOU LIKE A LARGER 
 SCALE)
 ## SPECIES1: 4:160
 ## SPECIES2: RAMPED UP FROM SPECIES 1  
 ## SPECIES3: RAMPED UP FROM SPECIES 2  
 ## ABUNDANCES: SHOULD STAY THE SAME AS THE RANGES BELOW
 ## DIETS: variable, with higher values for richer communities

 #1,2,3 REFERS TO TROPHIC LEVEL, AND THE VALUES OF THE SEQ REPRESENT THE 
 RANGE OF THE ALPHA PARAMETER

x <- 2
repeat {

  species1<- (2*x):(2*x+x)  
  abundance1<-250:600
  species2<-(2*x+2*x):(3*x+2*x)
  abundance2<-250:600
  diet2<-seq((1+x/150),(2+x/40),by=0.1)
  #diet2<-seq((1+x/20),(2+x/20),by=0.1)
  species3<-(2*x+3*x):(3*x+3*x)
  abundance3<-100:400
  diet3<-seq((1+x/20),(2+x/20),by=0.1)

 ## ALSO, BUMP UP THE NUMBER OF ECOSYSTEMS TO WHATEVER YOU'D LIKE. HERE 
 I HAVE 10 COMMUNITIES  
 necosystems<-10

  ## parameters:  



  for (t in 1:necosystems){

  ##  formulation:  food web setup/interaction list 

## The following lines are where individual variable levels are selected 
## randomly
t1species<-sample(species1,1,replace=T) 
t1abundance<-sample(abundance1,1,replace=T)
t2species<-sample(species2,1,replace=T)
t2abundance<-sample(abundance2,1,replace=T) 
t2diet<-sample(diet2,1,replace=T)
t2alpha<-t2diet
t3species<-sample(species3,1,replace=T) 
t3abundance<-sample(abundance3,1,replace=T) 
t3diet<-sample(diet3,1,replace=T)
t3alpha<-t3diet

## The following three sections create log-normal densities of species
## the three trophic groups. The second and third groups have additional column
## for diet breadth based the pareto distributions.
## create lognormal deviations from mean:  
t1deviates<-rlnorm(t1species,meanlog=0,sdlog=1) 
##  convert those deviations to individual densities based on overall abundance
##  + 0.5 rounds out zeros
t1counts<-round(t1deviates*t1abundance/sum(t1deviates)+0.5)
## create matix and ther respective abundace per species 
trophic1<-matrix(0,nrow=t1species,ncol=2)
trophic1[,1]<-1:t1species   ## populate matrix with species numbers
trophic1[,2]<-t1counts      ## populate matrix with their counts

## matrix created the same as above but with additional column for diet breadths
t2deviates<-rlnorm(t2species,meanlog=0,sdlog=1) 
t2counts<-round(t2deviates*t2abundance/sum(t2deviates)+0.5)
alpha<-t2alpha; k<-exp(1)
## individual diet breadths created for each unique species
#t2dietbreadth<-VGAM::dparetoII(1:t2species,scale=alpha,shape=k)
t2dietbreadth<-rFlooredParetoI(t2species,alpha=alpha, maxval=t1species)
#t2dietbreadth
#hist(t2dietbreadth)


#t2dietbreadth<-round((t1species*t2dietbreadth)+0.5)
trophic2<-matrix(0,nrow=t2species,ncol=3)
trophic2[,1]<-1:t2species
trophic2[,2]<-t2counts
trophic2[,3]<-t2dietbreadth

## matrix created the same as above but with additional column for diet breadths
t3deviates<-rlnorm(t3species,meanlog=0,sdlog=1) 
t3counts<-round(t3deviates*t3abundance/sum(t3deviates)+0.5)
alpha<-t3alpha; k<-exp(1)
## individual diet breadths created for each unique species
#t3dietbreadth<-VGAM::dparetoII(1:t3species,scale=alpha,shape=k)
t3dietbreadth<-rFlooredParetoI(t3species,alpha=alpha, maxval=t2species)

#t3dietbreadth<-round((t2species*t3dietbreadth)+0.5)
trophic3<-matrix(0,nrow=t3species,ncol=3)
trophic3[,1]<-1:t3species
trophic3[,2]<-t3counts
trophic3[,3]<-t3dietbreadth

plants<-rep(trophic1[,1],trophic1[,2])
interactions<-matrix(0,nrow=length(plants),ncol=7,byrow=F)

interactions[,1]<-plants

herbivores<-matrix(0,nrow=1,ncol=2)
enemies<-matrix(0,nrow=1,ncol=2)

i<-1
length<-nrow(trophic2)
while (i <= length){
  food<-sample(trophic1[,1],trophic2[i,3],replace=T)
  data<-matrix(c(rep(trophic2[i,1],trophic2[i,2]),rep(food,each=1,len=trophic2[i,2])),ncol=2,byrow=F)
  herbivores<-rbind(herbivores,data)
  i<-i+1
}
rownames(herbivores)<-1:nrow(herbivores)

i<-1
length<-nrow(trophic3)
while (i <= length){
  food<-sample(trophic2[,1],trophic3[i,3],replace=T)
  data<-matrix(c(rep(trophic3[i,1],trophic3[i,2]),rep(food,each=1,len=trophic3[i,2])),ncol=2,byrow=F)
  enemies<-rbind(enemies,data)
  i<-i+1
}
rownames(enemies)<-1:nrow(enemies)

i<-1
length<-nrow(interactions)
while (i <= length){
  plant<-interactions[i,1]
  if (any(herbivores[,2]==plant)){
    row<-sample(rownames(herbivores[herbivores[,2]==plant,,drop=F]),1,replace=F) ####!!!!!!XXXXXXX
    interactions[i,2]<-herbivores[row,1]
    herbivores<-herbivores[!rownames(herbivores) %in% row,,drop=F]
  }         

  herbivore<-interactions[i,2]
  if (any(enemies[,2]==herbivore)){
    row<-sample(rownames(enemies[enemies[,2]==herbivore,,drop=F]),1,replace=F) #####
    interactions[i,3]<-enemies[row,1]       
    enemies<-enemies[!rownames(enemies) %in% row,,drop=F]
  }

  i<-i+1
}  

interactions[,4]<-paste(interactions[,1],interactions[,2],sep="_")
interactions[,5]<-paste(interactions[,2],interactions[,3],sep="_")
interactions[,6]<-paste(interactions[,1],interactions[,2],interactions[,3],sep="_")

interactions[,4]<-gsub("(\\d+)(_0)(_0)", "0" , interactions[,4], perl=T )
interactions[,4]<-gsub("(_0)", "" , interactions[,4], perl=T    )
interactions[,5]<-gsub("(\\d+)(_0)(_0)", "0" , interactions[,5], perl=T )
interactions[,5]<-gsub("(_0)", "" , interactions[,5], perl=T    )
interactions[,6]<-gsub("(\\d+)(_0)(_0)", "0" , interactions[,6], perl=T )
interactions[,6]<-gsub("(_0)", "" , interactions[,6], perl=T    )
interactions[,7]<-t*x

interactions<-data.frame(interactions)
names(interactions)<-c("plant","herbivore","enemy","int.PH","int.HE","int.PHE","ecosystem")


nsurveys<-nrow(interactions)  #or #nsurveys = 500
survey<-sample(1:nrow(interactions),nsurveys,replace=F) ## or #survey<-sample(1:nrow(interactions),nsurveys,replace=T)

subsamples<-interactions[survey,]


outfile<-"Ecosystem.txt"
if (file.exists(outfile)){write.table(interactions,file = outfile, 
                                      append = T,quote = F,sep = " ",   
                                      row.names = F,col.names=F)
} else { 
  write.table(interactions,file = outfile, 
              append = T,quote = F,sep = " ",
              row.names = F,col.names=T)
    }

  } ## end t loop ##  

  x = x+2
  if (x > 90){
    break
  }
}

stopImplicitCluster()
```

Answer (score 1):

The abundances are too low and the starting plant richness is also too low. Make these changes near the beginning of your code and you'll get mostly good pareto distributions with alpha correlated with plant species richness:

```
x <- 10
repeat {
species1<- (2*x):(2*x+x)    
abundance1<-2500:6000
species2<-(2*x+2*x):(3*x+2*x)
abundance2<-1000:4000
diet2<-seq((x/100),(1+x/100),by=0.1)
species3<-(2*x+3*x):(3*x+3*x)
abundance3<-500:1400
diet3<-seq((x/200),(1+x/200),by=0.1)

necosystems<-10
```

Comment: Thanks @Gusanero for the solution! Easier than I thought. PS. Thanks for not being one of those jerky stackoverflow responders.